# JComponents Disappears once I add a BorderLayout Direction

Tags: java, swing

The program draws completely fine if the border layout is Center, but not for any other direction. Here is the code below.

```
    public class MainVisualizer {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    int windowWidth = 1000;
    int windowHeight = 850;
    
    JFrame mainFrame = new JFrame("Plotter and Integration Visualizer ");
    mainFrame.setSize(windowWidth, windowHeight);
    
    mainFrame.add(new GraphComponent(windowWidth, windowHeight), BorderLayout.EAST);
    
    mainFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    mainFrame.setVisible(true);

}
```

}
public class GraphComponent extends JComponent {

```
private ArrayList<String> textFunctions;
private int frameWidth;
private int frameHeight;

public GraphComponent(int width, int height) {
    this.textFunctions = new ArrayList<>();
    this.frameHeight = height;
    this.frameWidth = width;

}

@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g;
    g2.drawLine(0, frameHeight/2, frameWidth, frameHeight/2);//X axis
    g2.drawLine(frameWidth/2, 0, frameWidth/2, frameHeight);//Y axis
    System.out.println( this.getX()+" "+ this.getY());
    g2.drawString("X", frameWidth/2, frameHeight/2);
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe what you are seeing is because you haIven't set preferred size. The default is 0, and so that's what you get when you add not to the center

```
public class GraphComponent extends JComponent {

private ArrayList<String> textFunctions;
private int frameWidth;
private int frameHeight;

public GraphComponent(int width, int height) {
    this.textFunctions = new ArrayList<>();
    this.frameHeight = height;
    this.frameWidth = width;

    //Set preferredSize right here
    setPreferredSize(new Dimension(width, height));
    ///////////////
}

@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g;
    g2.drawLine(0, frameHeight/2, frameWidth, frameHeight/2);//X axis
    g2.drawLine(frameWidth/2, 0, frameWidth/2, frameHeight);//Y axis
    System.out.println( this.getX()+" "+ this.getY());
    g2.drawString("X", frameWidth/2, frameHeight/2);
}
}
```

Comment: Nitpick - Prefer overriding `getPreferredSize` instead of using `setPreferredSize`, it prevents the possibility that some one else will call it - but context matters ;).  I'd also recommend not relying on `frameWidth/Height` and instead look at using `getWidth` and `getHeight` of the component

Comment: @MadProgrammer Nitpick with your nitpick :) I think in this case using setPreferredSize is better, because it allows OP to pass in arbitrary values in the constructor as s/he is doing that could change on a case to case basis. But I do agree with you about using getWidth/getheight in paintComponent

Comment: Yes, you can still pass parameters to the constructor - I would argue that, in this cases, it's more imperative to prevent the `preferredSize` been changed by overriding `getPreferredSize` and using the values passed to the constructor (since we're recording them anyway) - but, context is king.  What are the design intentions?  As a general rule of thumb, it's discouraged to use `setPreferredSize` and let the component itself do it's actually sizing calculations itself, just saying ;)

Comment: @MadProgrammer Re: "setPreferredSize is bad" - agreed. We're on the same page, just nitpicking each other :)